# Online searchable manual for TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, documentation

Having used psTricks for years, I'd though I'd drag myself into the modern era and start using TikZ.  So far, I like it very much.  However, the only manual I can find is the 500+ page PDF manual, which although comprehensive, detailed and thorough, is not always easy to find things in.  Is there an online, HTML or similar, fully searchable version of the manual?

Thanks,
Alasdair

Comment: I have found that generally the index and the table of contents (let it be displayed in the sidebar of your pdf viewer) are the best way to navigate the TikZ manual. After a while you will have a pretty good idea where to find information about any given topic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The PDF is fully searchable. Simply use the search functionality of you PDF viewer or the hyperlinked index at the end or, like me, both (e.g. go to the start of the index using the PDF bookmarks and start to search there after the macro you are looking for).

There is http://www.texample.net/tikz/, especially http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/manual/
which has many of the examples of the TikZ manual and other LaTeX examples, but I don't think there is a full HTML version of the manual. Converting all the pictures to images, or even SVG, wouldn't be efficient.

While Google and other search engines provide HTML versions of PDFs in general, the TikZ/PGF manual "`pgfmanual`" is to large for that. AFAIK the maximum size for this online service is 1MB or so.

Answer (score 3):

This is an unofficial HTML version of the documentation of tikz and pgfplots maintained by Dominik Peters (produced using the [lwarp](https://ctan.org/pkg/lwarp?lang=en) package):

- tikz: https://tikz.dev/
- pgfplots: https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/

Answer (score 1):

here is an optio in format html:
https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/contrib/tex-contrib/beamer/pgf-1.01/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-tex4ht/en/pgfmanual.html

Comment: This is a link to the manual version `1.01` which dates back to 2005, since then there have been `1.18`; `2.10`; `3.0.1a` and today we are at version `3.1`. 
This `1.01` manual  has 248 pages, today it has 1282!
Nevertheless, in my opinion, learning Tikz from this version is enough to get started.

Comment: here is an option uptaded with several tex files for you can download the complete package in a local folder on your computer, and edit the tex file that has the indexes of the manual because probably the pdf of the manual was generated from the tex file, and then you can include hyperlinks in the index for redirect to the sections and chapters you want. Just edit the tex file and include the links via hyperlinks and then regenerate the pdf file. Obviously you should keep all files in the same folder for this to work.  https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Answer (score 1):

Pour les francophones (in french)
http://math.et.info.free.fr/TikZ/bdd/TikZ-Impatient.pdf