# Materials for learning TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, documentation, tutorials

I feel intimidated in learning TikZ. I was wondering if there are some nice materials (or just your replies) at different level:

1. for providing big picture, which is
   important to beginners to not lose
   direction during learning.
2. for comprehensive reference.

Examples are important, but only examples are not always clear for understanding the big picture and organization.

Comment: The manual has both extended examples and a reference. Is it not to your liking?

Comment: @Matthew: There are too many details and it is suitable for comprehensive reference. Is there some concise one?

Comment: then you are welcome to skim through the only first chapter.

Comment: Related questions: [Online searchable manual for TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/online-searchable-manual-for-tikz), [What is the minimum one needs to know to use TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9116/what-is-the-minimum-one-needs-to-know-to-use-tikz)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I learned through just [the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). It starts with *great* tutorials. I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 32):

TikZ, in common with Beamer and Memoir, is a very, very rich, and, as a result, intimidating, package, so don't feel too bad about it.

The way I learned all three was basically demand-driven --- "learning by doing". Whenever I needed something "new", I'd dig into the manual and try stuff until either it worked (not always most elegantly), or in desperation go to the [examples website](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/), or moan here on TeX-'n-Friends. Occasionally supplemented by trying to answer "challenging" questions here.

After what --- one or two years --- that additional effort has worked like a savings account, and I now have the three tools on my belt, with which I can do almost everything I need. I still need to go back to the manuals, but it's a lot easier now.

Answer (score 20):

You could also try to learn by example: http://www.texample.net/tikz/
after having a look at the manual first.

Answer (score 16):

In addition to the excellent manual, try M R C van Dongen's *LaTeX and Friends*. It not only introduces you to `pgf`, but also `pgfplots` and `beamer`. It is available on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642238157).

Comment: Thanks! How does learning pgf, pgfplots and beamer help learning Tikz? Or how are they related to Tikz?

Comment: Thanks! (1) What is the difference between "graphics" and "plots"? (2) how does Tikz fit into the suite: pgf, pgfplots and beamer? Is Tikz "graphics", "plot", "presentations", or something else?

Comment: To quote from [van Dongen's website](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LaTeX-and-Friends.html): "Due to copyright restrictions I had to remove the preliminary version of my book on LaTeX and Friends. ...". Amazon shows [a print version available at the end of 2011](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/3642238157/)

Comment: One may find part of the book still at http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/LAF.pdf

Answer (score 15):

If you read French, there's an excellent guide for the impatient at http://math.et.info.free.fr/TikZ/index.html.  And in the Cahiers Gutenberg there's a tutorial by [Yves Soulet](http://cahiers.gutenberg.eu.org/cg-bin/article/CG_2008___50_5_0.pdf), and another by [Till Tantau](http://cahiers.gutenberg.eu.org/cg-bin/article/CG_2007___48_23_0.pdf) himself.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for sharing this great resource.

Answer (score 15):

If you are intimidated the Tikz manual then I would suggest a much shorter PDF
by Mertz and Slough from TUGboat volume 30 at:
http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-2/tb95mertz.pdf and another example, a little bit longer with more depth is a "Minimal Introduction to Tikz" that you can find on the CTAN site [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). But really, the Tikz manual is excellent and authoritative. Thanks to Jasper Loy for the manual he pointed out and, finally, let me mention the excellent site for PGFPlots for those interested in examples of mathematical plots that can be downloaded (a la TEXample.net) at:
http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 8):

#### [PDF VisualTikz](https://ctan.org/pkg/visualtikz)

Visual help for TikZ based on im­ages with min­i­mum text: an im­age per com­mand or pa­ram­e­ter. For example, see this illustrations for line junctions:

[image]

This document is still 200 pages large!

Answer (score 4):

As a simple starting point, I would like to add *Quack Guide No. 2
The Morse code of TikZ*, section 3 from the [second DuckBoat](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb39-1/tb121duck-tikz.pdf) by prof. van Duck, TUGboat, Volume 39 (2018), No. 3.

<sup>Errata corrige: `text dept` of Figure 2 should have been `text depth`, of course.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I share @Martin opinion, you could try to learn by example.

- You can find ready examples with the latex code in: http://www.texample.net/tikz/
- For examples with a detailed description, you can check: https://latexdraw.com/

Comment: My embarrassing university blocks the second site as having ‘inappropriate content.’  I will try to educate them about the meaning of LaTeX…

Comment: @Thérèse Lol, I am not sure they will change their mind.

Answer (score 0):

There is a book that seems beginner-friendly called [Tikz CookBook](https://kochiuyu.github.io/tikz/tikz-cookbook/). It focuses on "Diagrams in Economics", but I'm guessing you do not need to know much about economics to learn TikZ from it.