# How can I draw an aircraft diagram using Latex/tikz ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I want to draw an aircraft diagram with three axes (longitudinal, lateral and normal) using latex/tikz. I also need three views (top, side, and front) of it.

Comment: Can you give us a link to an example of such a diagram? Please be more specific!

Comment: Why do you need to use TikZ? Perhaps you could create the illustration in Inkscape and include the pdf in your LaTex document? You might find that easier. Plus, I doubt anyone is going to just create the illustration that you're describing without you first trying.

Comment: How far have you gotten in drawing such a diagram? If you want a good answer you should provide a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5701). Have you started [to learn TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15779/5701)?

Comment: Start with the tail and proceed nosewise :). TikZ is not well suited for 3d modelling, so usually you cannot obtaing different views just by switching a few parameters here and there.

Comment: Why not try something like: [sketch2sketch](http://www.falkoschindler.de/sketch2sketch/) or this [sketch3d](http://www.fauskes.net/nb/introduction-to-sketch/) ?

Comment: @ipvalic: Yes you can!  Sraw it using `xyz` coordinates and then simply change the `x`, `y`, and `z` vectors.

Comment: @Tom: Nice, but obviously done in an external program (look at the maths).

Comment: @Andrew: no idea about the maths, but [this comment](http://www.fauskes.net/nb/introduction-to-sketch/#c480) claims that the drawing is done in Sketch 3D and hence uses either TikZ or PSTricks

Answer (score 4):

[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) provides an export option [where you use LaTeX](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/LaTeX) for typesetting the text. That might be a solution if you want to draw using a visual editor but still use LaTeX for setting any text.

Answer (score 2):

Probably best to use a vector graphics editor such as [Ipe](http://ipe7.sourceforge.net/) (retains the same fonts for the graphics as specified for your document).

To use the graphic (e.g. *fig1.eps*) produced by the editor put `\usepackage{graphicx}` in your preamble and to use the picture somewhere in your document use `\includegraphics{path/fig1}`.