# Sankey Diagram not rendering proper

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I've found this website very useful for the past few months without ever needing to post a question but alas the time has come where I actually need to make a post, hopefully someone might be able to help me out here. So here goes...

I've been using LaTeX to write my thesis and all has gone well so far. I have 64-bit version of MikTex 2.9.5105 installed on my computer. I've been trying to figure out how to draw Sankey Diagrams and came across the answer by Paul Gaborit on [How to draw a Sankey Diagram using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40159/how-to-draw-a-sankey-diagram-using-tikz)

[The source code from TeXample](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/sankey-diagram/) is given below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfdeclarelayer{sankeydebug}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground,sankeydebug}

\newif\ifsankeydebug

\newenvironment{sankeydiagram}[1][]{

  \def\sankeyflow##1##2{% sn, en
    \path[sankey fill]
    let
    \p1=(##1.north east),\p2=(##1.south east),
    \n1={atan2(\x1-\x2,\y1-\y2)-90},
    \p3=(##2.north west),\p4=(##2.south west),
    \n2={atan2(\x3-\x4,\y3-\y4)+90}
    in
    (\p1) to[out=\n1,in=\n2] (\p3) --
    (\p4) to[in=\n1,out=\n2] (\p2) -- cycle;
    \draw[sankey draw]
    let
    \p1=(##1.north east),\p2=(##1.south east),
    \n1={atan2(\x1-\x2,\y1-\y2)-90},
    \p3=(##2.north west),\p4=(##2.south west),
    \n2={atan2(\x3-\x4,\y3-\y4)+90}
    in
    (\p1) to[out=\n1,in=\n2] (\p3)
    (\p4) to[in=\n1,out=\n2] (\p2);
  }


  \tikzset{
    sankey tot length/.store in=\sankeytotallen,
    sankey tot quantity/.store in=\sankeytotalqty,
    sankey min radius/.store in=\sankeyminradius,
    sankey arrow length/.store in=\sankeyarrowlen,
    sankey debug/.is if=sankeydebug,
    sankey debug=false,
    sankey flow/.style={
      to path={
        \pgfextra{
          \pgfinterruptpath
          \edef\sankeystart{\tikztostart}
          \edef\sankeytarget{\tikztotarget}
          \sankeyflow{\sankeystart}{\sankeytarget}
          \endpgfinterruptpath
        }
      },
    },
    sankey node/.style={
      inner sep=0,minimum height={sankeyqtytolen(##1)},
      minimum width=0,draw=none,line width=0pt,
    },
    % sankey angle
    sankey angle/.store in=\sankeyangle,
    % sankey default styles
    sankey fill/.style={line width=0pt,fill,white},
    sankey draw/.style={draw=black,line width=.4pt},
  }

  \newcommand\sankeynode[4]{%prop,orientation,name,pos
    \node[sankey node=##1,rotate=##2] (##3) at (##4) {};
    \ifsankeydebug
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{sankeydebug}
      \draw[red,|-|] (##3.north west) -- (##3.south west);
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\len}{sankeyqtytolen(##1)/3}
      \draw[red] (##3.west)
      -- ($(##3.west)!\len pt!90:(##3.south west)$)
      node[font=\tiny,text=black] {##3};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \fi
  }

  \newcommand\sankeynodestart[4]{%prop,orientation,name,pos
    \sankeynode{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(##3)},rotate=##2]
      \path[sankey fill]
      (##3.north west) -- ++(-\sankeyarrowlen,0)
      -- ([xshift=-\sankeyarrowlen/6]##3.west)
      -- ([xshift=-\sankeyarrowlen]##3.south west)
      -- (##3.south west) -- cycle;
      \path[sankey draw]
      (##3.north west) -- ++(-\sankeyarrowlen,0)
      -- ([xshift=-\sankeyarrowlen/6]##3.west)
      -- ([xshift=-\sankeyarrowlen]##3.south west)
      -- (##3.south west);
    \end{scope}
  }

  \newcommand\sankeynodeend[4]{%prop,orientation,name,pos
    \sankeynode{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(##3)},rotate=##2]
      \path[sankey fill]
      (##3.north east)
      -- ([xshift=\sankeyarrowlen]##3.east)
      -- (##3.south west) -- cycle;
      \path[sankey draw]
      (##3.north east)
      -- ([xshift=\sankeyarrowlen]##3.east)
      -- (##3.south west);
    \end{scope}
  }

  \newcommand\sankeyadvance[3][]{%newname,name,distance
    \edef\name{##2}
    \ifstrempty{##1}{
      \def\newname{##2}
      \edef\name{##2-old}
      \path [late options={name=##2,alias=\name}];
    }{
      \def\newname{##1}
    }
    \path
    let
    % sankey node angle
    \p1=(##2.north east),
    \p2=(##2.south east),
    \n1={atan2(\x1-\x2,\y1-\y2)-90},
    % sankey prop
    \p3=($(\p1)-(\p2)$),
    \n2={sankeylentoqty(veclen(\x3,\y3))},
    % next position
    \p4=($(##2.east)!##3!-90:(##2.north east)$)
    in
    \pgfextra{
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\prop}{\n2}
      \pgfinterruptpath
      \sankeynode{\prop}{\n1}{\newname}{\p4}
      \path (\name) to[sankey flow] (\newname);
      \endpgfinterruptpath
    };
  }

  \newcommand\sankeyturn[3][]{%newname,name,angle
    \edef\name{##2}
    \ifstrempty{##1}{
      \def\newname{##2}
      \edef\name{##2-old}
      \path [late options={name=##2,alias=\name}];
    }{
      \def\newname{##1}
    }
    \ifnumgreater{##3}{0}{
      \typeout{turn acw: ##3}
      \path
      let
      % sankey node angle
      \p1=(##2.north east),
      \p2=(##2.south east),
      \p3=($(\p1)!-\sankeyminradius!(\p2)$),
      \n1={atan2(\x1-\x2,\y1-\y2)-90},
      % sankey prop
      \p4=($(\p1)-(\p2)$),
      \n2={sankeylentoqty(veclen(\x4,\y4))},
      \p5=(##2.east),
      \p6=($(\p3)!1!##3:(\p5)$)
      in
      \pgfextra{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\prop}{\n2}
        \pgfinterruptpath
        % \fill[red] (\p3) circle (2pt);
        % \fill[blue](\p6) circle (2pt);
        \sankeynode{\prop}{\n1+##3}{\newname}{\p6}
        \path (\name) to[sankey flow] (\newname);
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      };
    }{
      \typeout{turn acw: ##3}
      \path
      let
      % sankey node angle
      \p1=(##2.south east),
      \p2=(##2.north east),
      \p3=($(\p1)!-\sankeyminradius!(\p2)$),
      \n1={atan2(\x1-\x2,\y1-\y2)+90},
      % sankey prop
      \p4=($(\p1)-(\p2)$),
      \n2={sankeylentoqty(veclen(\x4,\y4))},
      \p5=(##2.east),
      \p6=($(\p3)!1!##3:(\p5)$)
      in
      \pgfextra{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\prop}{\n2}
        \pgfinterruptpath
        % \fill[red] (\p3) circle (2pt);
        % \fill[blue](\p6) circle (2pt);
        \sankeynode{\prop}{\n1+##3}{\newname}{\p6}
        \path (\name) to[sankey flow] (\newname);
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      };
    }
  }

  \newcommand\sankeyfork[2]{%name,list of forks
    \def\name{##1}
    \def\listofforks{##2}
    \xdef\sankeytot{0}
    \path 
    let
    % sankey node angle
    \p1=(\name.north east),
    \p2=(\name.south east),
    \n1={atan2(\x1-\x2,\y1-\y2)-90},
    % sankey prop
    \p4=($(\p1)-(\p2)$),
    \n2={sankeylentoqty(veclen(\x4,\y4))}
    in
    \pgfextra{
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\iprop}{\n2}
    }
    \foreach \prop/\name[count=\c] in \listofforks {
      let
      \p{start \name}=($(\p1)!\sankeytot/\iprop!(\p2)$),
      \n{nexttot}={\sankeytot+\prop},
      \p{end \name}=($(\p1)!\n{nexttot}/\iprop!(\p2)$),
      \p{mid \name}=($(\p{start \name})!.5!(\p{end \name})$)
      in
      \pgfextra{
        \xdef\sankeytot{\n{nexttot}}
        \pgfinterruptpath
        \sankeynode{\prop}{\n1}{\name}{\p{mid \name}}
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      }
    }
    \pgfextra{
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\diff}{abs(\iprop-\sankeytot)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\finish}{\diff<0.01?1:0}
      \ifnumequal{\finish}{1}{}{
        \message{*** Warning: bad sankey fork (maybe)...}
        \message{\iprop-\sankeytot}
      }
    };
  }

  \tikzset{
    % default values,
    declare function={
      sankeyqtytolen(\qty)=\qty/\sankeytotalqty*\sankeytotallen;
      sankeylentoqty(\len)=\len/\sankeytotallen*\sankeytotalqty;
    },
    sankey tot length=100pt,
    sankey tot quantity=100,
    sankey min radius=30pt,%
    sankey arrow length=10pt,%
    % user values
    #1}
}{
}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]

  \begin{sankeydiagram}[
    sankey tot length=90pt,%
    sankey tot quantity=6,%
    sankey min radius=15pt,%
    sankey fill/.style={
      draw,line width=0pt,
      fill,
      lime!50,
    },
    sankey draw/.style={
      draw=black,
      line width=1pt,
      line cap=round,
      line join=round,
    },
    %sankey debug,
    ]
    \sankeynodestart{6}{-90}{p0}{0,100};
    \sankeyadvance{p0}{50pt}

    \sankeyfork{p0}{3/p1,3/p2}

    \sankeyturn{p1}{90}
    \sankeyadvance{p1}{20pt}

    \sankeyadvance{p2}{60pt}

    \sankeyfork{p2}{2/p3,1/p4}

    \sankeyturn{p3}{90}
    \sankeyadvance{p3}{50pt}

    \sankeyfork{p3}{1/p5,1/p6}

    \sankeyadvance{p5}{70pt}

    \sankeyfork{p1}{1/p7,1/p8,1/p9}
    \sankeyadvance{p7}{50pt}
    \sankeyadvance{p9}{50pt}

    \sankeyadvance{p4}{40pt}
    \sankeyturn{p4}{90}
    \sankeyadvance{p4}{65pt}

    \sankeyadvance{p7}{40pt}

    \sankeynode{3}{0}{p11}{[shift={(50pt,-15pt)}]p7}
    \sankeyfork{p11}{1/p7a,1/p9a,1/p5a}
    \path (p7) to[sankey flow] (p7a);
    \path (p9) to[sankey flow] (p9a);
    \path (p5) to[sankey flow] (p5a);
    \sankeyadvance{p11}{30pt}
    \sankeynodeend{3}{0}{p11}{p11}

    {
      \tikzset{
        sankey fill/.append style={
          line width=0pt,
          lime!50!green!50,
        }
      }
      \sankeyturn{p8}{-90}
      \sankeyadvance{p8}{40pt}

      \sankeyturn{p6}{-90}
      \sankeyturn{p4}{-90}

      \sankeynode{3}{-90}{p10}{[shift={(-15pt,-60pt)}]p8}
      \sankeyfork{p10}{1/p8a,1/p6a,1/p4a}
      \path (p4) to[sankey flow] (p4a);
      \path (p6) to[sankey flow] (p6a);
      \path (p8) to[sankey flow] (p8a);
      \sankeyadvance{p10}{30pt}
      \sankeynodeend{3}{-90}{p10}{p10}
    }



  \end{sankeydiagram}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I could run this on another 32 bit computer flawlessly but it does not parse well on the 64 bit computer. The diagram is all a jumbled mess like;

[image]

Is there something simple I'm missing here. I'm a novice here and barely understand LaTeX and learning it as I go and this seems to be a simple issue but a bit out of my grasp in troubleshooting. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Instead of linking to some source code hosted somewhere else, please make your question self-contained by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I get the output you get. I have no idea what it's supposed to look like:-) It is unlikely to be the 32/64 difference probably a newer package somewhere add `\listfiles` on line 2 and compare the list that is printed at the end of the log, probably you have different package versions on the two machines

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Thanks for your response ! I will check it out and let you know. I have a meeting with my advisor now and just got dumped with some work that I have to finish before the meeting . I will try doing what you said and report back in a few hours.

Comment: Also sorry about the formatting in the question. Thanks  @percusse for making the corrections.

Comment: That code started life on this site, and its author was here today according to his profile so I left a message on his original answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40159/how-to-draw-a-sankey-diagram-using-tikz

Comment: See the last answer to the Sankey question, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173489/586 The `atan2` function changed between PGF 2.1 and PGF3, swapping the order of inputs.

Comment: I think I rather prefer this version of the diagram.  It reminds me of [this](http://www.trinity.edu/jdunn/spiderdrugs.htm)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I edited my original answer to correct this bug (since TikZ/PGF v3.0, the arguments of `atan2` are swapped).

Comment: @PaulGaborit Confirmed. It works ! This is a good piece of code ! (Comment edited to add in confirmation of code working)

Comment: @PaulGaborit Can you cook up a small answer to this regarding your update?

Comment: Looks really cool though.

Comment: Is this already an exhibit at some art gallery? If not, it should. Also, when that is the case, please tell me where. I would like to stand in front of it wearing a turtleneck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since TikZ/PGF v3.0, the arguments of atan2 are swapped:

```
atan2(x, y) % TikZ/PGF before v3.0

atan2(y, x) % TikZ/PGF v3.0
```

Therefore the code in the [Sankey Diagram example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88821) must be adapted to this new version of TikZ/PGF.

Comment: I think this change in the behavior of the arc tangent was poorly commented

Comment: @rpapa This change is not poorly commented. It is not documented at all!

Comment: Je pense que tu devrais faire une question sur tex.stackexchange  pour que la réponse devienne visible, sinon cela ne va être qu'au travers de réponse à des questions comme celle-ci.

Comment: @rpapa Faire une question à quel sujet ?

Comment: justement, sur la modification du comportement de atan, mais je ne sais pas s'il y en a la possibilité sur stackexchange//
-----------------------------------------
precisely the behavior modification atan, but I do not know if there is the possibility of StackExchange