# Joining two thin lines into thicker one

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to have 2 thin lines and 1 thick line join each other in the middle, with a smooth transition from the thin lines to the thick one. Currently, this looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to have the thin lines join into the thicker one more smoothly? For example, I am imagining the lines to enter at the top and at the bottom of the thicker line, effectively melding into each other.

Using this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[-, ultra thick] (0,2) -- (1,2.5) -- (0,3);
    \draw[-, line width=2mm]  (1,2.5) to (2,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sort of related, but possibly overkill: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40159/how-to-draw-a-sankey-diagram-using-tikz

Comment: That's a great link, thank you! Naturally, using my search terms I didn't find that one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you make sure the thin line width is half the thick line, you can use a `to` path with appropriate angles and coordinates.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[-, line width=1mm] (0,2) to[out=30,in=180] (1,2.5cm-0.5mm) ++(0,1mm) to[out=180,in=-30] (0,3);
    \draw[-, line width=2mm]  (1,2.5) to (2,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `to` and `--`?

Comment: @SinglePackAbs You can't set the angles (`out` and `in`) like I did here  with `--`. In general, `to` is more sophisticated than `--`, see section 14.13 *The To Path Operation* in the manual, and e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55069/ for one example

Answer (score 5):

The following doesn't look too bad (but is in no way automated):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[-, line width=1mm] (0,2) to (1,2.5);
    \draw[-, line width=1mm] (0,3) to (1,2.5);
    \draw[-, line width=2mm]  (0.9,2.5) to (2,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]