# Tikz: merging three parallel lines into one bigger arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

I have a tikz drawing with three parallel lines, and one big arrow. I would like those three lines to merge into the large one at its beginning. Does anyone have any suggestion how I can do this?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \resizebox{0.7\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
    \node[draw=none, fill=none] (sender) {};
    \node[draw=none, fill=none, right =6cm of sender] (provider) {};

    \coordinate (wall) at ([xshift=-2.5cm]provider.west);

    \draw[transform canvas={yshift=4.5ex}, line width = 2pt] (sender) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above] {Line 1} (wall);
    \draw[transform canvas=, line width = 2pt] (sender) --node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above] {Line 2} (wall);
    \draw[transform canvas={yshift=-4.5ex}, line width = 2pt] (sender) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above] {Line 3} (wall);
    \draw[transform canvas=,->, line width = 5pt] (wall) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above=1em] {Large line} (provider);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372374) for inspiration

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=2mm and 12mm,
  A/.style = {single arrow, draw=gray, fill=gray, 
              single arrow head extend=1.5mm,
              minimum height=12mm, minimum width=12mm,
              outer sep=0mm},
box/.style = {rectangle, draw, minimum size=12mm},
                        ]
\node (s)   [box]               {sender};
\node (a)   [A,right=of s]      {};
\node (r)   [box,right=0mm of a]{receiver};
%
\coordinate[above=of s.east] (sa);
\coordinate[below=of s.east] (sb);
%
\draw[very thick]   
        (sa)        --    (a.tail |- sa)
        (s.east)    --    (a)
        (sb)        --    (a.tail |- sb);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*note:*

- never put float environment between `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}`
- please never send only code snippet. Always provide minimal working example (*mwe*), a small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In preamble load only to your problem relevant packages.

Comment: No, I want the three thin lines to merge into the large one

Comment: ok, then lines are without arrow heads .. you only need to delete them. done in edited answer.

Comment: @Ziva, any news?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

As Zarko told you, I've used `\centering` instead of `center` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.7\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
            \node[draw=none, fill=none] (sender) {};
            \node[draw=none, fill=none, right =6cm of sender] (provider) {};

            \coordinate (prewall) at ([xshift=-3cm]provider.west);
            \coordinate (wall) at ([xshift=-2.5cm]provider.west);

            \draw[line width = 2pt] ([yshift=4.5ex]sender.east) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above] {Line 1} ([yshift=4.5ex]prewall) -- ([shift={(1pt,1pt)}]wall.west);
            \draw[transform canvas=, line width = 2pt] (sender) --node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above] {Line 2} (prewall) -- (wall.west);
            \draw[line width = 2pt] ([yshift=-4.5ex]sender.east) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above] {Line 3} ([yshift=-4.5ex]prewall) -- ([shift={(1pt,-1pt)}]wall.west);
            \draw[transform canvas=,->, line width = 5pt] (wall) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above=1em] {Large line} (provider);
        \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]