# Two headed fat flow arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, flow-charts

What is the best way to draw this kind of arrow using Tikz?
[image]

I cant provide any MWE, because of simplicity of question for which I found no info.

Is there an elegant solution or some Tilz library or package?

Comment: These are very much like sankey diagram arrows https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40159/how-to-draw-a-sankey-diagram-using-tikz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No competitor to any of the nice arrows [mentioned by percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40159/how-to-draw-a-sankey-diagram-using-tikz).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- ++(3,0) -- ++(0,0.5) -- ++(2,-1) --++(-2,-1)
-- ++(0,0.5)-- ++(-1,0) -- ++(0,-0.5) arc (0:-90:0.5)
-- ++(-1,0) -- ++(0,-0.25) -- ++(-1,0.5) -- ++(1,0.5)
-- ++(0,-0.25) -- ++(0.75,0) to[out=0,in=-90] ++(0.25,0.25)
-- ++(0,0.25) -- ++(-1.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution fits my purposes much better. Thank you