# How to draw Sankey diagram with Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to make a Sankey diagram. I know it's possible with Tikz picture but I don't get the hang of it. I'm trying to make something like this:
[image: Diesel ICE losses]
Is there anyone who has experience with this package?

Comment: We know that you are not able to draw this completely, but could you please provide all what you have tried?

Comment: First I started looking at some other questions e.g : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40159/how-to-draw-a-sankey-diagram-using-tikz. But I have no clue on how to start with this. Is there a pdf that explains it step by step?

Comment: What we are asking about is an example code. At least you should know we do not want to draw everything from scratch.

Comment: Maybe I asked it the wrong way, my english is not that good. I didn't mean to ask drawing it yourself from scratch. What I meant to ask was, is there any pdf that explains this step by step? Because when looking at other examples the code doesn't make sense to me at all. I started using Latex a few weeks ago.. But to answer your question, no I don't have an example code or at least not somethin that I tried

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a `just-do-it-for-me` question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not easy to understand the accepted answer in your reference question, however, with some simple calculations we can draw it quite directly as follows.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[{Triangle Cap[reversed]}-,line width=1cm] (0,0) -- (1.5,0);
\draw[-{Triangle[width=.35cm*1.5,length=.35cm]},line width=.35cm] (1.5,.5) -- ++ (0,-2);
\draw[-{Triangle[width=.3cm*1.5,length=.3cm]},line width=.3cm] (2.5,.5) -- ++ (0,-2);
\draw[-{Triangle[width=.14cm*1.5,length=.14cm]},line width=.14cm] (3.5,.5) -- ++ (0,-2);
\draw[-{Triangle[width=.21cm*1.5,length=.21cm]},line width=.21cm] (3.5,.395) -- ++ (2,0);
\draw[line width=.65cm] (1.5,.175) -- (2.5,.175);
\draw[line width=.35cm] (2.5,.325) -- (3.5,.325);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adding the text, changing the color, and rescaling the picture so that it fits your document are what you have to do now. Hope you can do it!

Comment: Thanks a lot! What does this part mean '(1.5,.5) -- ++ (0,-2);'

Comment: @GaetaanA I can write `(1.5,.5) -- (1.5,-1.5)`, they are the same. Basically `++` helps you to "shift" coordinates.

Answer (score 7):

Even though I only have claws my <s>hand</s>claw writing is more readable than yours, I think.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\newcounter{ahead}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ahead/.style={/utils/exec=\stepcounter{ahead},
insert path={ -- ++ (0,#1/2) -- ++(#1,-#1) coordinate(ahead-\number\value{ahead}) --
++ (-#1,-#1) -- ++(0,#1/2) }},nodes={align=center}]
 \draw (0,0) coordinate(start) -- ++(0.75,0.75) -- ++ (-0.75,0.75) 
 node[below left]{100\%\\ Diesel}
 -- ++(10,0) [ahead=1] -| ++(-3,-3) coordinate(aux)  [rotate=-90] 
 (aux)[ahead=0.6,rounded corners=4pt] |-++(-2.5,0) [sharp corners] 
 |- ++(2,-1.5) [ahead=0.8,rounded corners=4pt]
 |-++(-2,0) [sharp corners]  |- ++(2,-1.5) [ahead=0.8,rounded corners=8pt] -| (start);
 \path (ahead-1) node[right] {Tank in total\\ 21\%}
 (ahead-2) node[below right] {unreadable\\ xx\%}
 (ahead-3) node[below] {unreadable\\ xx\%}
 (ahead-4) node[below] {unreadable\\ xx\%};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, the width of the arrows must (or should) be proportional to its value, i.e. 14% arrow must be thinner than 35% arrow.

Comment: @JouleV Thanks! Yes, you can adjust this with the argument of the `ahead`, which precisely takes one argument that controls its width. More precisely, you can adjust this *if* you can read the numbers on the screen shot, which I can't.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes my writing is unreadable haha, anyway thanks. i'll try to adjust the width and color myself now :) what is says is 'exhaust loss, cooling loss, mechanical & radiation loss'