# What is this diagram called and how can I create one in LaTex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

What are these splitted flows of data called and is there a tikz/pgf library that can generate them?

I have looked at https://tikz.dev/ for similar diagrams but found nothing similar.

[image]

Comment: Search for “Sankey” and then try to do it yourself. There are many people here willing to help when you have a concrete problem. -show compilable code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [Sankey diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram).
There is the [sankey package](https://ctan.org/pkg/sankey) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40159/how-to-draw-a-sankey-diagram-using-tikz).