# Problems about drawing a map and learn to draw with TeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, technical-drawing

I'm doing a beamer, and now I encounter a problem. I want to draw a map in my beamer like this 
[image]

Who can help me?

I'm now still not very familiar with these things. Also I want to learn some basic skills to draw with LaTeX. Could any one  give me some materials or advice to learn?

Comment: We have plenty of other questions regarding drawing in TeX (mostly via Tikz/PGF). For a set of references for beginners in Tikz, see e.g. [Materials for learning Tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15779).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your block diagrams are relatively simple, images can be created with a few simple (non-graphical) tools:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\stacktype{L}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\fboxsep=5pt
\begin{document}
\stackanchor{$\xrightarrow{U~}$}{$\xrightarrow{V~}$}
\stackunder{\fbox{\fboxsep=1pt\fbox{M}}}{sim}
$\xrightarrow{\textrm{GDH}(U,V)}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i compile your code on my computer it says "File `stackengine.sty' not found. \usepackage"

Comment: @Alex, Package is at http://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine.  You can get the .sty file and put it in your current directory, if you don't know how to install it on your system.