# Node next to other tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to write a code to get a network package structure.

```
        1          var         4
-------------------------------------
|   Control   |    Casa   |   Mia   |
```

Currently I have the code below, but I have noticed that I get two lines in stead of 1 between the cell Control and Casa. Any help?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\usepackage[spanish]{translator}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}

%TikZ stuff
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,automata,plotmarks,positioning} 


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=1.5]
    \tikzstyle{every path}=[draw, font=\small]

    \node[right,draw, minimum width=2cm,minimum height=0.8cm,fill=white](b0) {Control};
    \node[right=0cm of b0, draw, minimum width=2cm,minimum height=0.8cm,fill=white](b0) {Casa};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Edit 1:

Now I have this, but figure is not center, and don't now how to make a line from the corners of control to get to the total of the other row[image]

```
\begin{figure}    
\newcommand{\size}{\linewidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=1]
    \tikzstyle{every path}=[draw, font=\small]

    \node[right,draw, minimum width=0.15*\size,minimum height=0.8cm,fill=white](b0) {Control};
    \node[above=-0.2 of b0, minimum width=0.15*\size,minimum height=0.8cm] {1};
    \node[above left=-0.2 and -0.5 of b0, minimum width=0.2*\size,minimum height=0.8cm] {byte};

    \node[right=0cm of b0, draw, minimum width=0.2*\size,minimum height=0.8cm,fill=white](b1) {Longitud};
    \node[above=-0.2 of b1, minimum width=0.2*\size,minimum height=0.8cm] {1};      

    \node[right=0cm of b1, draw, minimum width=0.6*\size,minimum height=0.8cm,fill=white](b2) {Valor};
    \node[above=-0.2 of b2, minimum width=0.6*\size,minimum height=0.8cm] {8};      


    \node[below left=1 and -2 of b0 ,draw, minimum width=0.2*\size,minimum height=0.8cm,fill=white](h0) {Bloqueo};
    \node[below=-0.2 of h0, minimum width=0.15*\size,minimum height=0.8cm] {1};
    \node[below left=-0.2 and -0.5 of h0, minimum width=0.15*\size,minimum height=0.8cm] {bit};

    \node[right=0cm of h0, draw, minimum width=0.3*\size,minimum height=0.8cm,fill=white](h1) {M\'{a}ximo n$^o$ intentos};
    \node[below=-0.2 of h1, minimum width=0.2*\size,minimum height=0.8cm] {3};      

    \node[right=0cm of h1, draw, minimum width=0.2*\size,minimum height=0.8cm,fill=white](h2) {RSV};
    \node[below=-0.2 of h2, minimum width=0.2*\size,minimum height=0.8cm] {1};      

    \node[right=0cm of h2, draw, minimum width=0.4*\size,minimum height=0.8cm,fill=white](h3) {Intentos restantes};
    \node[below=-0.2 of h3, minimum width=0.4*\size,minimum height=0.8cm] {3};



\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Mi figura}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: We have a few questions about this problem … You need `right=+-\pgflinewidth of b0`. Or `outer sep=+0pt` for all nodes.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I want it to look like a table

Comment: Maybe take a look at a `\matrix`. Should make your task easier.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel the problem is that I have to rows and one of them is like a zoom of one of the fields and I want to link it with lines

Comment: why not creating two matrices (one per row) and then connect the one cell to the second row with lines (for the callout effect)?

Comment: Did you try the [`bytefield` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/bytefield)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was suggested, I think `matrix` is a good option to draw byte and bit fields.
Next code show how to use two matrices with two rows each one and how to join their corners to represent that the second one is a detailed field.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}

%\begin{figure}    
\newcommand{\size}{\linewidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every path/.style={draw, font=\small},
     labelfield/.style={outer sep=0pt, minimum height=5mm,font=\small, anchor=center},
    field/.style={outer sep=0pt, draw, minimum height=8mm,
    minimum width=#1\size,font=\small,anchor=center}]

    \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    row 1/.style={nodes=labelfield}, row 2/.style={nodes={field=.15}}] {
    byte & 1 & 1 & 8 \\
     &  Control & |[field=.2]|Longitud &  |[field=.6]| Valor\\
    };

    \matrix (B) [matrix of nodes, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
            below=5mm of A,
            row 2/.style={nodes=labelfield}, 
            row 1/.style={nodes={field=.15}}] {
     &  |[field=.2]| Bloqueo & |[field=.3]|Màximo n\textdegree{}  intentos &  |[field=.2]| RSV & |[field=.2]| Intentos restantes\\
    bit & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3\\
    };

    \draw (A-2-2.south west) -- (B-1-2.north west);
    \draw (A-2-2.south east) -- (B-1-5.north east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that's lock exactly what I want ;) I'm new to tikz and still to much to learn. Where can I get a good tutorial? the manual is a bit hard.

Comment: @jlanza: I think first chapters of `TiKZ` manual is very good place to start. They are written as tutorials focused on different topics every one. But you can also explore answers to [Materials for learning TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15779/1952).