# The best way to start learning how to draw geometric figures in mathematics

Tags: packages, learning

I want to learn how to draw geometric figures using LaTeX, but I don't know where to start.
The problem is that I don't know any accessible manuals or guides that is suitable for me.
I learned LaTeX through 'The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX' and other packages through short manuals, but what I have found is that pgf/tikz manual is something like 1100 page; I just couldn't simply read it from the very first to the last.

Since I'm a beginner, I wish I could draw basic geometric figures that come up in basic geometry texts such as [Kiselev's geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0977985202).
I need a recommendation for a package that I need to use and any guides that I can start looking up.
The guide shouldn't be too overwhelming, but introducing what I need right from the start.
If there is a thorough guide, you can still recommend it for reference.
The closest thing I can handle related to geometrical figures is a commutative diagram with tikzcd.

I wonder how an experienced LaTeX user started learning this subject!

Comment: The tikz manual begins with a several tutorials (you can download it from ctan).  One thing to keep in mind is that all computer graphics is based on Cartesian coordinates and trigonometry rather than Euclidean constructions.  You can do construction, but not easily.

Comment: Hm, so just starting from the first page of tikz manual is the best way?

Comment: If you want to learn TikZ: Yes. The tutorials are very good. After reading them your can consider the rest of the manual as reference to look up certain things. There’s also [`tkz-euclide`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide) but unfortunately its only documented in french …

Comment: Gotta take my time learning tikz. I know a bit of French so might look tkz-euclide as well.

Comment: If you speak german, you may also have a look at my blog: http://tobiw.de/tbdm/tikz-adventskalender

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: @Johannes_B Unfortunately I couldn't find any document readily accessible. http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf this helped me somewhat. Considering the discussion in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15779/materials-for-learning-tikz, I guess there's no easy way of learning it...