# Graphs in TeX or LaTeX

Tags: diagrams

Is it possible to draw graphs like the image below in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please add alwasy a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I think this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15779/101651 could be useful for you if you would like to learn `tikz`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another Tikz solution.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  State/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=2mm,fill=black,circle},
  node distance=2cm and 1cm
  ]
  \node[State,label=180:V5] (V5) at (0,0){};
  \node[State,label=180:V1,above=of V5] (V1){};
  \node[State,label=-90:V4,right=of V5] (V4){};
  \coordinate[right=of V4](V2base);%% Halfway between V4 and V3
  \node[State,label=0:V3,right=of V2base] (V3){};
  \node[State,label=90:V2] (V2) at (V2base |- V1){};
  \node[State,label=180:V6] (V6) at ({$(V5)!0.5!(V4)$} |- {$(V5)!0.5!(V1)$}){};
  \draw (V1)--(V2)--(V3)--(V4)--(V5) (V4)--(V2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `pstricks`. You can compile with `pdflatex` launching the compiler with the `--enable-write18` switch (MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, Mac TeX). Alternativeli, remove  `auto-pst-pdf` loading and compile via `latex + dvips + pstopdf` or via `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\psset{colsep=1.5cm, rowsep=2cm, dotsize=6pt, labelsep=2pt}%
\sffamily
 \begin{psmatrix}
 %%% Matrix nodes
 \dotnode{1} & & \dotnode{2} \\
 \dotnode{5} & \dotnode{4} & &\dotnode{3}
 %%% Connections
  \ncline{1}{2}\ncline{2}{3}\ncline{3}{4}\ncline{4}{5}\ncline{2}{4}
\ncline[linestyle=none]{1}{4}\ncput{\dotnode{6}}
\nput{180}{1}{V1}\nput{90}{2}{V2}\nput{0}{3}{V3}
\nput{-120}{4}{V4}\nput{180}{5}{V5}\nput{180}{6}{V6}
 \end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Do we want to miss a solution with a `tikz matrix`? Of course not!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{%
    mypoint/.style={circle, fill=black},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[column sep=.5em, row sep=4ex, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=6pt] (M) {%
    \node[mypoint, label={[left,xshift=-4pt]V1}] (V1) {}; & & & & & \node[mypoint, label={above:V2}] (V2) {}; \\
    & \node[mypoint, label={left:V6}] (V6) {}; \\
    \node[mypoint, label={[left,xshift=-4pt]V5}] (V5) {}; & & \node[mypoint, label={below left:V4}] (V4) {}; & & & & & & \node[mypoint, label={[right,xshift=2pt]V3}] (V3) {};\\
};
\draw (V1) -- (V2);
\draw (V5) -- (V4) -- (V3);
\draw (V4) -- (V2);
\draw (V2) -- (V3);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like your coding @CarLaTeX

Comment: i like your code and i understand it but i can ask you what about draw self loop by using your code or can you help my to graph

Comment: @MaryamFasfous The `\matrix` is more or less like a `tabular`. Did you read the post linked to my comment to your question? To learn `tikz` I suggest to you to read the tutorial at the beginning of the TikZ & PGF manual. If you have other questions, don't hesitate to post them!

Comment: thak you very much but can you but link in comment  here

Comment: @MaryamFasfous This one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15779/materials-for-learning-tikz

Answer (score 2):

```
    \documentclass{article} 
    \usepackage{tikz} 
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning} 
    \begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture} 

    \tikzset{
    pics/my circle/.style = {
    background code = { \fill circle [radius=#1]; }
    }
    }
    \tikz [fill=black]
    \draw  (-0.2,0)node[left] {$V_{1}$} pic {my circle=1mm} -- (2,0) node[right] {$V_{2}$} pic {my circle=1mm};
    \draw (-0.6,0.2)-- (1,-1) pic {my circle=1mm};
    \draw (-0.6,0.2)-- (-1.5,-1) pic {my circle=1mm} node[below] {$V_{4}$};
    \draw  (-2.5,-1) node[left] {$V_{5}$} pic {my circle=1mm} -- (1,-1) node[right] {$V_{3}$} ;
    \draw (-1.5,-0.3) node[left] {$V_{6}$} pic {my circle=1mm};

    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer doesn't need (or take advantage of) the `positioning` TikZ library.