# How to draw stack and queue data structure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw a stack data structure to explain it in first concept course as well  as queue.[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[draw, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.5cm] 
\node[draw] (in) at (-1,2) {};
\node[draw] (out) at (1,-2) {}; 
\matrix (queue)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw, nodes={draw}}, nodes in empty cells] { \\ \\ \\ \\ }; 
\draw[-latex] (0.25,-1) .. controls (0.25,-1.25) and (1,-1.25) .. (out.north); 
\draw[-latex] (in.south) .. controls (-1, 1.5) and (-0.25,1.5) .. (-0.25,1); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: found an example using matrix but does not fit to my need

Comment: Post it anyway.

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture}[draw, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.5cm]
    \node[draw] (in) at (-1,2) {};
    \node[draw] (out) at (1,-2) {};
    \matrix (queue)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw, nodes={draw}}, nodes in empty cells]
    {
       \\ \\ \\ \\
    };

    \draw[-latex] (0.25,-1) .. controls (0.25,-1.25) and (1,-1.25) .. (out.north);
    \draw[-latex] (in.south) .. controls (-1, 1.5) and (-0.25,1.5) .. (-0.25,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you a start (anyway I am now in freetime :))

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    queue element/.style={
        draw,very thin,rounded corners,
        fill=yellow!30,
        minimum width=1cm,minimum height=.5cm,
        font=\sffamily\footnotesize
    },
    >={[scale=0.8]Triangle}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[green!20] (5.1,.35) rectangle (-.6,-.35);
\draw[green,thick,>->] (-.6,.35) -- (5.1,.35);
\draw[green,thick,>->] (-.6,-.35) -- (5.1,-.35);
\foreach \i/\name in {1/C,2/B,3/A}
    \node[queue element] (\name) at (1.5*\i,0) {\name};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]A.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {front};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]C.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {rear};
\path (6,0) node[right] {before};
\node[queue element] (D) at (-2,1) {D};
\draw[->,very thick] (D.south) to[out=-90,in=180] (-.7,0);

\scope[yshift=-3cm] % queue after
\fill[green!20] (5.1,.35) rectangle (-.6,-.35);
\draw[green,thick,>->] (-.6,.35) -- (5.1,.35);
\draw[green,thick,>->] (-.6,-.35) -- (5.1,-.35);
\foreach \i/\name in {0/D,1/C,2/B,3/A}
    \node[queue element] (\name) at (1.5*\i,0) {\name};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]A.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {front};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]D.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {rear};
\path (6,0) node[right] {after};
\endscope
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A little modification and you will have `dequeue()` instead of `enqueue()`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    queue element/.style={
        draw,very thin,rounded corners,
        fill=yellow!30,
        minimum width=1cm,minimum height=.5cm,
        font=\sffamily\footnotesize
    },
    >={[scale=0.8]Triangle}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[green!20] (5.1,.35) rectangle (-.6,-.35);
\draw[green,thick,>->] (-.6,.35) -- (5.1,.35);
\draw[green,thick,>->] (-.6,-.35) -- (5.1,-.35);
\foreach \i/\name in {0/D,1/C,2/B,3/A}
    \node[queue element] (\name) at (1.5*\i,0) {\name};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]A.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {front};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]D.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {rear};
\draw[->,very thick] (5.2,0) to[out=0,in=90] ++ (1,-1);
\path (6,0) node[right] {before};

\scope[yshift=-3cm] % queue after
\fill[green!20] (5.1,.35) rectangle (-.6,-.35);
\draw[green,thick,>->] (-.6,.35) -- (5.1,.35);
\draw[green,thick,>->] (-.6,-.35) -- (5.1,-.35);
\foreach \i/\name in {0/D,1/C,2/B}
    \node[queue element] (\name) at (1.5*\i,0) {\name};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]B.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {front};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]D.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {rear};
\path (6,0) node[right] {after};
\endscope
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the same technique, you can also illustrate `stack` data structure :)

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    queue element/.style={
        draw,very thin,rounded corners,
        fill=yellow!30,
        minimum width=1cm,minimum height=.5cm,
        font=\sffamily\footnotesize
    },
    >={[scale=0.8]Triangle}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[green!20] (5.1,.35) rectangle (-.6,-.35);
\draw[green,thick] (-.6,.35) -- (5.1,.35) |- (-.6,-.35);
\foreach \i/\name in {1/C,2/B,3/A}
    \node[queue element] (\name) at (1.5*\i,0) {\name};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]A.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {rear};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]C.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {front};
\path (6,0) node[right] {before};
\node[queue element] (D) at (-2,1) {D};
\draw[->,very thick] (D.south) to[out=-90,in=180] (-.7,0);

\scope[yshift=-3cm] % stack after
\fill[green!20] (5.1,.35) rectangle (-.6,-.35);
\draw[green,thick] (-.6,.35) -- (5.1,.35) |- (-.6,-.35);
\foreach \i/\name in {0/D,1/C,2/B,3/A}
    \node[queue element] (\name) at (1.5*\i,0) {\name};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]A.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {rear};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]D.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {front};
\path (6,0) node[right] {after};
\endscope
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    queue element/.style={
        draw,very thin,rounded corners,
        fill=yellow!30,
        minimum width=1cm,minimum height=.5cm,
        font=\sffamily\footnotesize
    },
    >={[scale=0.8]Triangle}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[green!20] (5.1,.35) rectangle (-.6,-.35);
\draw[green,thick] (-.6,.35) -- (5.1,.35) |- (-.6,-.35);
\foreach \i/\name in {0/D,1/C,2/B,3/A}
    \node[queue element] (\name) at (1.5*\i,0) {\name};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]A.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {rear};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]D.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {front};
\draw[->,very thick] (-.7,0) to[out=180,in=90] ++ (-1,-1);
\path (6,0) node[right] {before};

\scope[yshift=-3cm] % stack after
\fill[green!20] (5.1,.35) rectangle (-.6,-.35);
\draw[green,thick] (-.6,.35) -- (5.1,.35) |- (-.6,-.35);
\foreach \i/\name in {1/C,2/B,3/A}
    \node[queue element] (\name) at (1.5*\i,0) {\name};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]A.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {rear};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]C.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {front};
\path (6,0) node[right] {after};
\endscope
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, and for stack if i may? it will be vertical

Comment: @mourad Stack version added (the illustration is only the way I like, because I don't know how your stack looks like)

Comment: is it possible to rotate it 90°?

Comment: You can modify my code. It seems like you are a new Ti*k*Z user, so you may need to look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15779/156344, after that you will be able to modify my code to even 45 degrees if you want

Answer (score 2):

A little variation on [JouleV's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489992/1952) solution.

I've used a `matrix of nodes` to declare the `queue` which can be also used for an horizontal or vertical stack. The `matrix` node can be used as `background area` and no external rectangle is needed for it.

Internal nodes are conveniently labelled as `front` and `rear` to avoid using particular names.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, matrix, positioning}
\tikzset{
    queue element/.style={
        draw,very thin,rounded corners,
        fill=yellow!30,
        minimum width=1cm,minimum height=.5cm,
        font=\sffamily\footnotesize
    },
    >={[scale=0.8]Triangle},
    queue/.style={matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        nodes={queue element, anchor=center},
        fill=green!20,
        column sep=5mm,
        row sep=2mm,
    },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix[queue] (Q1) {
|(rear)| D & C & B &|(front)| A\\};
\draw[green,thick,>->] (Q1.north west) -- (Q1.north east);
\draw[green,thick,>->] (Q1.south west) -- (Q1.south east);
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]front.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {front};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]rear.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {rear};
\draw[->,very thick] (Q1.east) to[out=0,in=90] node[pos=.6, above right] (aux) {before} ++ (1,-1);

\scope[yshift=-2cm] % queue after
\matrix[queue] (Q1) {
|(rear)| D & C &|(front)| B &|[fill=none, draw=none]| \\};
\draw[green,thick,>->] (Q1.north west) -- (Q1.north east);
\draw[green,thick,>->] (Q1.south west) -- (Q1.south east);
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]front.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {front};
\draw[<-] ([yshift=.2cm]rear.north) -- ++ (0,.5) node[above] {rear};
\node at (aux|-Q1) {after};
\endscope
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix[queue] (Q1) {
|[fill=none, draw=none]| \\
|(front)| C\\
B\\
|(rear)| A\\};
\draw[green,thick,-] (Q1.north west) |-(Q1.south)-| (Q1.north east);
\draw[<-] ([xshift=.2cm]front.east) -- ++ (0:.5) node[right] {front};
\draw[<-] ([xshift=.2cm]rear.east) -- ++ (0:.5) node[right] {rear};
\draw[<-,very thick] (Q1.north) to[out=90,in=190] ++ (1,1) node[right, queue element] (D) {D};
\node[below=3mm of Q1.south east] {before};

\scope[xshift=3.5cm] % queue after
\matrix[queue] (Q1) {
|(front)| D \\
 C\\
B\\
|(rear)| A\\};
\draw[green,thick,-] (Q1.north west) |-(Q1.south)-| (Q1.north east);
\draw[<-] ([xshift=.2cm]front.east) -- ++ (0:.5) node[right] {front};
\draw[<-] ([xshift=.2cm]rear.east) -- ++ (0:.5) node[right] {rear};
\node[below=3mm of Q1.south east] {after};
\endscope
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[lazy/.style={rounded corners,fill=gray!30,draw=gray!50,
minimum width=3em,minimum height=4ex},arr/.style={very thick,-stealth},
arr2/.style={very thick,stealth-},font=\sffamily]
 \begin{scope}[start chain=going left,node distance=1em,nodes={lazy,on chain}]
  \node[lazy] (A2){A};
  \node[lazy] (B2){B};
  \node[lazy] (C2){C};
  \node[lazy] (D2){D};
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \node[fit=(A2) (D2),top color=gray!20,bottom color=gray!10,inner sep=1em](F2){};
 \end{scope}
 \foreach \X in {north,south}
 {\draw[arr,gray!50]  (F2.\X\space west) -- (F2.\X\space east);}
 \begin{scope}[yshift=3cm,start chain=going left,node distance=1em,nodes={lazy,on chain}]
  \node[lazy] (A1){A};
  \node[lazy] (B1){B};
  \node[lazy] (C1){C};
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \node[fit=(A1) (D2.west|-A1),top color=gray!20,bottom color=gray!10,inner sep=1em](F1){};
 \end{scope}
 \foreach \X in {north,south}
 {\draw[arr,gray!50]  (F1.\X\space west) -- (F1.\X\space east);}
 \node[left=2em of F1.north west,lazy] (D1) {D};
 \draw[arr,black] (D1.south) to[out=-60,in=180] (F1);
 \draw[arr2] (A2|-F2.north) -- ++ (0,1em) node[above]{Front};
 \draw[arr2] (D2|-F2.north) -- ++ (0,1em) node[above]{Rear};
 \draw[arr2] (A1|-F1.north) -- ++ (0,1em) node[above]{Front};
 \draw[arr2] (C1|-F1.north) -- ++ (0,1em) node[above]{Rear};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]