# How to draw the triangle in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know how tow draw the:

`\triangle{ABC}`

it will show

[image]

but how can I draw the:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE, please show us what you have tried so-far in the form of an MWE. Please note that this site is not a `just-do-it-for-me` site.

Comment: I found all of the LaTeX mathetical  signals, do not found it. I only can found the $\triangle{ABC}$.

Comment: have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15779/materials-for-learning-tikz this may serve for you as a starting point.

Comment: `\triangle` is a symbol which does not even take an argument. You on the other hand do not want a symbol but to draw a triangle. You can search for "TikZ triangle" as a starting point.

Comment: You used the pgf-tikz tag. It is a good starting point. You must **draw** the triangle. How coud TeX guess you want this kind and size of trangle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A PSTricks solution only for either fun or comparison purposes. Compile it with `xelatex` or `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\pspicture(8,6)
\pstTriangle(1,1){A}(7,1){C}(7,5){B}
\pstRightAngle{A}{C}{B}
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `tikz`,

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0)node[below left]{A} -- 
  ++(2,0)node[below right]{C}coordinate(C) --
  ++(0,2)node[below right]{B} -- cycle;
  \draw (C) +(-3mm,0mm) |- +(0mm,3mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]