# Reproducing intersection of two curves in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I am looking to reproduce the figure below using tikz:

[image]

The codes that I have aren't producing this figure exactly.

```
   \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={text height=0.7em,text depth=0.25ex},
my arc/.style={insert path={(4,0)  arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=2]}},
my curve/.style={insert path={(0,0) to[out=-90,in=-135] (1,0) -- ++ (66:4)}}]
\begin{scope}
\clip[my curve] -| cycle;
\fill[red!20,my arc] -- ++ (0,-1) -- ++ (4,0);
\end{scope}
\draw (0,4) node[above left] {$x$} |- (5,0) node[below left] {$y$};
\draw[my arc] node[pos=0.1,above right]{$\alpha\, W(y)$};
\draw[my curve] node[right] {$P(y)$};
\draw (0,2) node[left]{$x^{*}$} -| (2,0) node[below] {$y^*$}
\draw (0,1.8) node[left]{$x_{0}$} -| (1.8,0) node[below] {$y_{0}$}
(0,1) node[left]{$a$} -- (2,1) node[above left]{Incentive-feasible set}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The $P(y)$ curve is too straight and the bottom is kind of flat. Also I cannot add $x_{0}$ and $y_{0}$ for some reason. My Texstudio editor would just collapse with it. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** With Schrodinger's cat's help:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={text height=0.7em,text depth=0.25ex},
my arc/.style={insert path={(4,0)  arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=2]}},
my curve/.style={insert path={(0,0) to[out=-90,in=-114,looseness=1.5] (1,0) -- ++ (70:4)}}]
\begin{scope}
\clip[my curve] -| cycle;
\fill[red!20,my arc] |- ++ (4,-1);
\end{scope}
\draw (0,4) node[above left] {$x$} |- (5,0) node[below left] {$y$};
\draw[my arc,name path=arc] node[pos=0.1,above right]{$\alpha\, W(y)$};
\draw[my curve,name path=curve] node[right] {$P(y)$};
% \draw  (0,2) node[left]{$x^{*}$} -| (2,0) node[below] {$y^*$};
\draw[name intersections={of=arc and curve,by={i0,i1}}] 
(i1-|0,0) node[left]{$x_{0}$} -| (i1|-0,0) node[below] {$y_{0}$}
-| (2.1,0) node[below] {$y^*$} node[anchor=east,yshift=6ex,align=left]{Incentive-\\ feasible set} ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This computes the intersection. The first code in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/541638/194703) also does.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={text height=0.7em,text depth=0.25ex},
my arc/.style={insert path={(4,0)  arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=2]}},
my curve/.style={insert path={(0,0) to[out=-90,in=-114,looseness=1.5] (1,0) -- ++ (66:4)}}]
 \begin{scope}
  \clip[my curve] -| cycle;
  \fill[red!20,my arc] |- ++ (4,-1);
 \end{scope}
 \draw (0,4) node[above left] {$x$} |- (5,0) node[below left] {$y$};
 \draw[my arc,name path=arc] node[pos=0.1,above right]{$\alpha\, W(y)$};
 \draw[my curve,name path=curve] node[right] {$P(y)$};
% \draw  (0,2) node[left]{$x^{*}$} -| (2,0) node[below] {$y^*$};
 \draw[name intersections={of=arc and curve,by={i0,i1}}] 
 (i1-|0,0) node[left]{$x_{0}$} -| (i1|-0,0) node[below] {$y_{0}$}
 (0,1) node[left]{$a$} node[anchor=west,yshift=-1.4ex,align=left]{Incentive-\\
 feasible set}
 -- (i1|-0,1) ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but how do I get the bottom part to be more round and the P(y) curve is to be a bit curvy?

Comment: @OGC In order to have a smooth result you need to adjust the in and out angles such that the in and the subsequent out differ by 180. I did that now.

Comment: @Schrondinger's cat Any suggestion on how I can get rid of the horizontal line with the label a?

Comment: @OGC Remove `(0,1) node[left]{$a$} node[anchor=west,yshift=-1.4ex,align=left]{Incentive-\\
 feasible set}
 -- (i1|-0,1)` (but keep the `;` in the end!).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've made an edit as well.

Comment: I want to be still able to have the label of Incentive-feasible set though.

Comment: @OGC Then use `\draw[name intersections={of=arc and curve,by={i0,i1}}] 
 (i1-|0,0) node[left]{$x_{0}$} -| (i1|-0,0) node[below] {$y_{0}$}
 (0,1) node[left]{$a$} node[anchor=west,yshift=-1.4ex,align=left]{Incentive-\\
 feasible set} ;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've made an edit to get close to the figure I wanted.