# Producing diagrams in TikZ or similar

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'd like to produce a diagram like this

[image]

Is it even possible in Ti*k*Z?

MWE of my attempt

```
%\documentclass{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}% better visibility

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % First Horizontal Line and Vertical Lines
    \draw [thick] (0,0) -- (5,0);
    \draw [thick] (0,-0.2) -- (0,0.2);
    \draw [thick] (5,-0.2) -- (5,0.2);
    
    % Second Horizontal Line and Vertical Lines
    \draw [thick] (6,0) -- (11,0);
    \draw [thick] (6,-0.2) -- (6,0.2);
    \draw [thick] (11,-0.2) -- (11,0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: What you try so far? Where you stuck?

Comment: It is, and it's not very complicated. Have a look into the tutorial part of https://tikz.dev/tutorials-guidelines .

Comment: how then? I have no idea how to use tikz

Comment: downvoting me isn't helping me to leatn

Comment: Please make a visible effort, people will be happy to help with the rest.

Comment: If MS-SPO's link was not to your liking, you can try [TikZ CTAN page](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), which provides a minimal tutorial.

Comment: About learning: a) read said tutorials, b) search here, c) try simple Tikz code yourself, d) search the web for the Tikz gallery (which also holds code). Just start, it's not that difficult.

Comment: And remember this site is not a `please do this for me` service. I would just draw this one graph (?) paper, then define `\coordinate` for the relevant points, and lastly draw the lines and add the text.

Comment: @GregoryHouse Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15779/materials-for-learning-tikz

Comment: If your solution to my problem is "just learn the language bro" then that's pretty sorry attempt at helping. I attached a MWE of an attempt

Comment: Please don‘t be angry, that‘s not the point. Both Latex and Tikz are complex enough, demanding for concrete code to give better answers. E.g. looking at your MWE it‘s obvious to  me, so I give the hint, that you should have a look into the manual for arrows.meta . That‘s the way it works here, as the other answers, not comments, demonstrate, too.

Answer (score 8):

Her is one just added ad hoc to the MWE

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % First Horizontal Line and Vertical Lines
    \draw [thick] (0,0) coordinate (Zero) -- (5,0) coordinate (A);
    \draw [thick] (0,-0.2) node[below] {\strut$0$} -- (0,0.2);
    \draw [thick] (5,-0.2) node[below] {\strut$a$} -- (5,0.2);
   
    % Second Horizontal Line and Vertical Lines
    \draw [thick] (6,0) coordinate (B) -- (11,0) coordinate (C);
    \draw [thick] (6,-0.2) node[below] {\strut$b$} -- (6,0.2);
    \draw [thick] (11,-0.2) node[below] {\strut$C$} -- (11,0.2);

    \coordinate (T0) at ($(Zero)+(0,-1)$);
    \coordinate (Ta) at ($(A)+(0,-1)$);
    \coordinate (Tb) at ($(B)+(0,-1)$);
    \coordinate (Tc) at ($(C)+(0,-1)$);

    \draw[<-] (T0) -- (Ta) node[pos=0.5,above] {\footnotesize $a\to0$};

    \draw[->] (Tb) -- ($(Tb)!0.45!(Tc)$);
    \draw[->] (Tc) -- ($(Tb)!0.55!(Tc)$);

    \coordinate (D) at ($(Tb)!0.5!(Tc)$);

    \node[above] at (D) {\footnotesize $b\to C$};

    \coordinate (E) at ($(T0)!0.5!(Ta)+(0,-0.5)$);

    \draw (E) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$0$};
    \draw ($(D)+(0,-0.5)$) coordinate(D') -- ++(0,-1) coordinate(D'') node[below]  {$bC$} ;

    \fill ($(D')!0.5!(D'')$) circle (2pt);
    

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It would be easier to first select initial coordinate(s) as a start point and then expand your diagram with the help of modifiers, rather than trying to calculate midpoints at for instance `0.2` let `Tikz` do the computing part

for example in the following code       `\coordinate (e) at ($(a)!0.5!(b)$);` the `0.5` acts as the `midpoint` between coordinates `a,b`

```
 \documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usetikzlibrary{angles,intersections,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (4,3);
    
    \coordinate[label=-90:A] (a) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (1,2);
    \coordinate [label=-90:C](c) at (3,0);
    \coordinate (d) at (3,2);
    
    \draw[red, line width=1pt] (a) -- (b);
    \draw[blue, line width=1pt] (c) -- (d); 
    \coordinate (e) at ($(a)!0.5!(b)$);
    \coordinate (f) at ($(c)!0.5!(d)$); 
    
    \draw[green, line width=1pt, shorten <=0.5pt, shorten >=0.5pt] (e) -- (f);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just to stimulate your programming skill, let's try some refactoring on your MWE:

- both lines are the same, besides their coordinates
- so let's perceive them as a `route`-object
- which `Tikz` can provide via a `\pic`
- which allows both replication of what you have already ...
- and new options

It's a good idea, to refactor code more often than not ;-)

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}% better visibility

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    route/.pic={% ~~~ refactoring duplicate parts ~~~
        \draw [thick] (0,0) -- (5,0);
        \draw [thick] (0,-0.2) -- (0,0.2);
        \draw [thick] (5,-0.2) -- (5,0.2);
    }
]
    % === Reproduction of what was already available =====
    % ~~~ First Horizontal Line and Vertical Lines
    \pic at (0,0) {route};    
    % ~~~ Second Horizontal Line and Vertical Lines
    \pic at (6,0) {route};
    
    % === New options ========
    % ~~~ going crazy to demonstrate \pics ~~~
    \pic[rotate=30,dotted]          at (45:4)   {route};    
    \pic[rotate=-15,red,scale=0.5]  at (45:4)   {route};    
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```