# Converting a static TikZ-sphere code into a command to place at arbitary locations

Tags: tikz-pgf, protein

I am wanting to use the code provided by [Tom Bombadil to 3D bodies in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42865/273733) that creates nice looking spheres, namely (with a slight adaption for showing the radius):

```
\draw (-1,0) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm);%
\draw[dashed] (-1,0) arc (180:0:1cm and 0.5cm);%
\draw (0,1) arc (90:270:0.5cm and 1cm);%
\draw[dashed] (0,1) arc (90:-90:0.5cm and 1cm);%
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);%
\shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.20] (0,0) circle (1cm);%
\fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);%
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- node[above left]{$r$} (1,0);%
```

which produces:

[image]

I am having difficulty in converting this code into a command that can be placed at arbitrary locations with the radius changed to another value that then updates the dependent values. My attempts do not work when using the `\the\numexpr#3/2cm` etc and I am not familiar enough with `tikz` as yet. For instance, when using a [simpler sphere code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/348623/273733) this is how my attempts at making it adaptable to different coordinates worked out:

[image]

My use case is to show 4-residue at a time spherical-searches of PDB alpha-carbon files to find helices (if all 4 alpha-carbon points lie in the sphere, high likelihood that it is in a helix region), which looks like this in my main `standalone` document:

[image]

How can I convert the above code into a custom command that can be placed at arbitrary locations and a modifiable radius please? Apologies that this is basic but I have been trying for half an hour and if I am struggling then perhaps others would too, would appreciate a duplicate if so (I have tried searching on here).

```
\documentclass[border=0pt,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}%
\newcommand\drawsphere[3]{%
    \draw (-1,0) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm);%
    \draw[dashed] (-1,0) arc (180:0:1cm and 0.5cm);%
    \draw (0,1) arc (90:270:0.5cm and 1cm);%
    \draw[dashed] (0,1) arc (90:-90:0.5cm and 1cm);%
    \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);%
    \shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.40] (0,0) circle (1cm);%
    \fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);%
    \draw[dashed] (0,0) -- node[above left]{$r$} (1,0);%
}%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\draw (-1,0) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm);%
\draw[dashed] (-1,0) arc (180:0:1cm and 0.5cm);%
\draw (0,1) arc (90:270:0.5cm and 1cm);%
\draw[dashed] (0,1) arc (90:-90:0.5cm and 1cm);%
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);%
\shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.20] (0,0) circle (1cm);%
\fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);%
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- node[above left]{$r$} (1,0);%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use ``\pic` instead of `\newcommand`, which you can place like nodes: https://tikz.dev/tikz-pics . Searching for `args` shows you how to pass parameters to a pic.

Comment: Be careful mixing canvas [coordinates/radii](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#sec-13.2.1) (the ones with unit) and those of the *xyz*  coordinate system (the one without units). Out of the box, PGF/TikZ defaults to 1 = 1cm and parallel axes so you're good here but full portability would look differently. (In this case, simply remove all `cm`s but leave the `1pt` but also see my comment to Rmano's answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although using `pics` would be better, a quick-and-dirty way:

```latex
\documentclass[border=2.7mm,tikz]{standalone}
\newcommand\drawsphere[3]{%scale, x, y
    \begin{scope}[scale=#1, shift={(#2,#3)}]
        \draw (-1,0) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm);
        \draw[dashed] (-1,0) arc (180:0:1cm and 0.5cm);
        \draw (0,1) arc (90:270:0.5cm and 1cm);
        \draw[dashed] (0,1) arc (90:-90:0.5cm and 1cm);
        \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
        \shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.40] (0,0) circle (1cm);
        \fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);
        \draw[dashed] (0,0) -- node[above left]{$r$} (1,0);
    \end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawsphere{1}{0}{0}
    \drawsphere{2}{2}{2}
    \drawsphere{0.5}{-1}{-1}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As noticed by Qrrbrbirlbel, the order of the `scale` option is important (scaling also the shift coordinates here), and also the central dot got scaled. Maybe a better implementation is

```latex
\documentclass[border=2.7mm,tikz]{standalone}
\newcommand\drawsphere[3]{%scale, x, y
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#2,#3)}, scale=#1,
            % transform shape % if you want the "r" scaled too
        ]
        \draw (-1,0) arc (180:360:1 and 0.5);
        \draw[dashed] (-1,0) arc (180:0:1 and 0.5);
        \draw (0,1) arc (90:270:0.5 and 1);
        \draw[dashed] (0,1) arc (90:-90:0.5 and 1);
        \draw (0,0) circle (1);
        \shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.40] (0,0) circle (1);
        \draw[dashed] (0,0) -- node[above left]{$r$} (1,0);
    \end{scope}
    \fill[black] (#2,#3) circle [radius=1pt];
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawsphere{1}{0}{0}
    \drawsphere{2}{2}{2}
    \drawsphere{0.5}{-1}{-1}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It should be noted that the order of `scale` and `shift` matter. The second sphere is placed at (4, 4) while the small one is placed at (−0.5, −0.5).` And this also scales the dot in the middle.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right. Probably it's better to switch the order; it's more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways to do it with `\pic`s, also showing work left to do. Main topics:

1. using `\pic` without parameter arguments
2. using `\pic` with parameter arguments

#### 1. without arguments

Simply rework the `\newcommand` like this:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    sph/.pic={% ~~~ with fixed radius ~~~~~~~~~
        \draw (-1,0) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm);%
        \draw[dashed] (-1,0) arc (180:0:1cm and 0.5cm);%
        \draw (0,1) arc (90:270:0.5cm and 1cm);%
        \draw[dashed] (0,1) arc (90:-90:0.5cm and 1cm);%
        \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);%
        \shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.20] (0,0) circle (1cm);%
        \fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);%
        \draw[dashed] (0,0) -- node[above left]{$r$} (1,0);%    
        }
    ]
...
```

and call it a bit like a \node, where the node here just acts as a caption:

```
    \pic at (0,0) {sph}; \node at (0,-1.3){1};
```

Now pics 1-5 show some variations of this call:

1. regular call
2. different color, rotated !! internal label "r" needs rework
3. same, made smaller >> unchanged label "r"
4. like 3, but subjecting also the label to scaling
5. enlarging it
6. miscounted for a reason == missing

[image: result]

#### with arguments

The `\tikzset` in the beginning shows you how to do it, while the call to use it is just --- kindly recognize passing the parameter:

```
\pic at (45:5) {sphr={2cm}};
```

Now, as you can see in picture 7 the work remains unfinished, as a bit more calculations are needed for all the arcs ... it's not just replacing `1cm` by `#1`. Perhaps the design approach here should be thought over and improved.

I.e. a successful rework needs to replace all hardcoded:

- `1cm`
- `+1` coordinate
- `-1` coordinate
- calculate the `half of #1` to replace the `0.5cm`

This can probably done better right from the start ... like:

- refactoring, like [discussed here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/694732/245790) , will help, i.e. introduce the solid AND dotted half-arcs as `\pic`
- and certainly [Qrrbirbirbel's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694722/converting-a-static-tikz-sphere-code-into-a-command-to-place-at-arbitary-locatio/694767#comment1724531_694722) should be taken into account

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{% ~~~ unfinished sketch for \pic taking argument(s) ~~~
    pics/sphr/.style args={#1}{% #1=radius, obviously
      code={
        \draw               (-1,0) arc (180:360:#1 and 0.5cm);%
        \draw[dashed]       (-1,0) arc (180:0:1cm and 0.5cm);%
        \draw               ( 0,1) arc (90:270:0.5cm and 1cm);%
        \draw[dashed]       ( 0,1) arc (90:-90:0.5cm and 1cm);%
        \draw               ( 0,0) circle (#1);%
        \shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.20] 
                            ( 0,0) circle (#1);%
        \fill[fill=black]   ( 0,0) circle (1pt);%
        \draw[dashed]       ( 0,0) -- node[above left]{$r$} (1,0);%     
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    sph/.pic={% ~~~ with fixed radius ~~~~~~~~~
        \draw (-1,0) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm);%
        \draw[dashed] (-1,0) arc (180:0:1cm and 0.5cm);%
        \draw (0,1) arc (90:270:0.5cm and 1cm);%
        \draw[dashed] (0,1) arc (90:-90:0.5cm and 1cm);%
        \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);%
        \shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.20] (0,0) circle (1cm);%
        \fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);%
        \draw[dashed] (0,0) -- node[above left]{$r$} (1,0);%    
        }
    ]
 
    \pic                            at (0,0) {sph}; \node at (0,-1.3){1};
    \pic[red,rotate=30]             at (5,0) {sph}; \node at (5,-1.3){2};
    \pic[scale=.5]                  at (3,0) {sph}; \node at (3,-.8 ){3};
    \pic[scale=.5,transform shape]  at (3,-2) {sph};\node at (3,-2.8){4};
    \pic[scale=2]                   at (-2,3) {sph};\node at (-2,.6){5};
    
    \pic                            at (45:5) {sphr={2cm}}; \node at (20:5.5){7};
 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, bookmarked as I have not heard of `\pic` before, hopefully this helps those in the future stuck on similar issues :)

Comment: Thanl you @JamesT, I promise you will benefit later : )