# Maintained version of tikz documentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, documentation

Is there maintained version of tikz and pgf documentation? The [webpage](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) doesn't state any but this [file](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) (pdf} is very useful.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. The pgf/TiKZ manual is distributed as part of pgf/TikZ and should be installed in your distribution and available using `texdoc` (at least on TeXLive.) It should match the version installed on your system.

Comment: The texdoc (which I was not aware of, thanks) does not have the very nice and detailed tutorial that tikz manual have.

Comment: `texdoc` also works with MikTeX (I currently have 2.9). It shows the latest manual you have installed on your system - if it is too old, you might have to update your packages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`pgfmanual`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) your already linked is the official PGF/TikZ manual. It should be installed together with the `pgf` and `tikz` packages. Try `texdoc pgf` in the command line to open it. Besides that there is http://www.texample.net/tikz/ with a lot of examples.

See also the following questions:
[Online searchable manual for TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/online-searchable-manual-for-tikz)
[Materials for learning TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15779/materials-for-learning-tikz)

Comment: The file I have linked to is from 2007 and the last version is from 2010. I don't mind that for now but eventually I am bound to find some crucial changes

Comment: @Yotam: The above link brings up the v2.10 manual which is from 2010/10/13. That's the official stable version.

Comment: @Yotam is is possible that you have a version of the pgf documentation installed in your local texmf folder? This might explain why you get the 2007 manual but have the 2010 version of pgf. Or is your entire tikz version from 2007?

Comment: @Alan: Even the v2.10 manual says ”Copyright 2007”  (but has the actual date and version displayed two pages later). Maybe this is the confusing part?

Answer (score 1):

You can find on my site a new version 05/01/2011   [altermundus.com](http://altermundus.com/pages/builds/index.html). You have the pgfmanual of the cvs version . I need to update all the files but there is a problem to compile some new parts actually !